# Google Groups to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, zapier, google-groups, google-groups-api

(G-Suite Forums asked me to post here since this was more of an API question)

Here's what I am trying to accomplish (as a G-Suite Admin):

I manage a number of Google "Groups"
I am sick and tired of manually adding/deleting people to these Groups (sometimes I call them old school "Email Distribution Lists;" regardless.

Now that our Salesforce is working wonderfully - I would like to automate the addition/deletion of contacts inside Groups by creating them in Salesforce and based on some fancy Salesforce wizardry (leave that to me) - have Salesforce, via Zapier zaps, pop into G-Suite Admin and "manage" my Groups membership.

This sounds great on paper, but this is seemingly not how it works.

So, my next idea...
I give Salesofrce/Zapier access to one of my Google Mailboxes (let's call it Salesforce.Integration Mailbox) and...
that mailbox somehow has perfect dynamic, real-time copies of each of my Groups inside its CONTACTS area.

Can THAT be done?

Any help/advice is appreciated.

: )

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the Enterprise Edition of Salesforce using Apex and the G Suite API.  Using Apex, you can call the G Suite API and create/update Groups and their Membership.  This can be triggered based on changes to data in Salesforce, like a field on the Contact or something.
An experienced Salesforce developer should be able to do this in 24 hours of work. [G Suite API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/get_started)